# How to decide packets whether it is uplink or downllink?

Tags: wireshark

I am having a  wireshark capture of scp from my machine end to another end. I want to know, how can I determine whether it is uplink or downlink packets?

**EDIT**

Uplink means that I am the source and downlink means I am the destination. As sitting in either the end point, we can say that one of them is uplink or downlink. But how do we know in case if it is router whether it is uplink or downlink?

Comment: First, you need to define what you mean by the terms "uplink" and "downlink." Packets are packets. They have source and destination IP addresses. You probably want to inspect those.

Comment: I think by "uplink" you mean source on your machine, and "downlink", destined to your machine. On capture, uplink packets will have as sourceIP your IP.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on you edit for the definition of uplink and downlink, You need to inspect the source and destination IP addresses. If your IP address is the source address, by your definition, it is an uplink packet. If the destination address is your IP address, by your definition, it is a downlink packet.

It doesn't matter if there is a router (or even multiple routers) in between. The router will not modify the packet addresses, except if it is doing NAT. Even with NAT, the packets you inspect on your host will have your host address as either the source or destination address.